# MIME type for XML sharing

Tags: android, mime-types, file-sharing

My app is generating XML files and would like to enable the sharing of these files between devices. If I use the `intent.setType("application/xml");` when starting the sharing activity, it produces only two options: Google Drive and Gmail.

I would like my app to be able to share over bluetooth. If I use `intent.setType("text/plain");` it will give me access to Google Drive, Gmail, Bluetooth, and then a bunch of options that won't work.

What MIME type can I use to get only Google Drive, Gmail, and Bluetooth? Or, how can I manually force the share activity to support Bluetooth?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that this is the best solution to the problem, but I used `intent.setType("audio/basic");`. This allows Bluetooth, Google Drive, and Gmail to be available with no other options.